# I can't color the entire newsletter popup

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento-2.1.7

I have created a backend button that makes me choose the color of the popup.I have created another button, but for the font color.
The font color works without any problem, but the background color gives me this problem
[image]
What can i do?

Comment: Here is the code:https://imgur.com/a/l9JE71r

Comment: try to add in your css display: inline-block; it will fill up with background color which is mentioned

Comment: Same problem..
But i don't know why with a big red x on the left corner

Comment: Please try below codes:
**`.modal-popup .modal-header {
 background: orange;
 border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}`**

Comment: and **`.modal-popup._inner-scroll .modal-content {
 background: orange;
}`**

Comment: I didnt define the color in this css file
I choose the color from a backend button
https://imgur.com/a/s0N759T(i changed it but its from here)

Comment: HERE you can find the entire code:https://imgur.com/a/l9JE71r

Answer (score 0):

Try the below css:

> .modal-inner-wrap{background:#ff0000;}

And remove background from color to none like below:

> .newsletter-content{background:none;}

After that you can adjust the css according to your requirement.

You can call your config color to **.modal-inner-wrap** and remove the background from **.newsletter-content**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I followed your instructions but the problem is the same.

Comment: Did you add that CSS to your file? And remove the inline CSS for newsletter-content for now

Comment: yes i added modal-inner-wrap and i added background-none to newsletter-content

Comment: What is the screenshot now?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/sQYkpAx

Comment: Front-end not code

Comment: You code is also not showing it's blurred.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/khHKRHM

Comment: can you add background-color to this class .modal-inner-wrap instead of popup-newsletter? Still backgroud is on block newsletter newsletter-content

Comment: i did it but isn't working

Comment: You didn't. As still css is on newsletter content not on .modal-inner-wrap

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ashsdTc

Comment: backgroud should be background

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/41LTx9Y

Comment: .modal-inner-wrap{background:#2DE3AB} add this in place of your code.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Again you have done something wrong. Paste the code here.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/LlS4Kox

Comment: And front-end screenshot?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/LlS4Kox

Comment: Pop-up screenshot

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PCMMZv1

Comment: CSS not loaded on frontend. Clean the cache and try again

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/RwyZ6Bh i did cache clean cache flush setup upgrade firefox cache clean